# Filewatcher to detect only files that are fully uploaded and are ready to copy

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, file-watcher

I would like to use Powershell filewatcher to monitor an azure file share to lock a file that is currently uploading until it has completed uploading. I have another function that copies the uploaded files to other file shares and I don't want the copy file function to copy a file before it has been completely uploaded successfully. Is this even possible. Someone suggested acquiring a lease file. Does anyone have an example of how to do this in Powershell.

Comment: This is a well-researched problem called [Producer-Consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). Several solutions exist on different use cases.

Comment: Thanks vonPryz, I guess I'm just looking for something that can confirms a) the file has no open handles b) the files is not currently open for writing by the sender ftp, sftp or copy. How can I be 100% sure the file I'm about to copy/move is complete?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Get-AzStorageFileHandle**

```
Get-AzStorageFileHandle
   [-ShareName] <String>
   [[-Path] <String>]
   [-Recursive]
   [-Context <IStorageContext>]
   [-ServerTimeoutPerRequest <Int32>]
   [-ClientTimeoutPerRequest <Int32>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-ConcurrentTaskCount <Int32>]
   [-IncludeTotalCount]
   [-Skip <UInt64>]
   [-First <UInt64>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Sample Snippet :

```
$storagecontext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<STORAGEACCOUNT NAME>" -StorageAccountKey "<KEY>"
Get-AzStorageFileHandle "<FILESHARENAME>" -Context $storagecontext -Recursive
```

**Sample Output :**

[image]

When I ran the command i was copying the search.py command

If you see a specific directory, coming up in the above commandlet you could safely assume that there is a operation happening in the directory and you could skip the directory from copying.